# How to implement SimpleConsumer in Kafka 2.0 version?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using kafka 2.0 version with scala some of apis are deprecated in 2nd version. Below

This is available in Kafka 0.9 and .8 versions but in 2nd version I didnt find any apis for SimpleConsumer `Map[TopicAndPartition, SimpleConsumer] = Map[TopicAndPartition, SimpleConsumer]()`

Like this some of below apis are not able to find in 2

- SimpleConsumer
- PartitionOffsetRequestInfo
- getOffsetsBefore
- OffsetRequest

Can you please help me out how to implement with using in scala.

Comment: `KafkaConsumer` should be used instead for all use-cases. What difficulties are you having with it?